# Covariant and countervariant interpretations of SEQ in AR

Tags: logic, model-theory, natural-numbers, beta-function

Let a *covariant interpretation* of model $\mathscr{M}$ in model $\mathscr{M}'$ be defined as a couple of functions $(f,g)$, with $f$ injective, such that $$f:D\hookrightarrow\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M}')$$$$g:\text{Rel}(\mathscr{M})\to\text{Rel}(\mathscr{M}')$$ $$\text{for any }\alpha\in\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M}) , R\in\text{Rel}(\mathscr{M})\quad\alpha\in R\iff f^\ast(\alpha)\in g(R)$$where $\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M}')$ is the set of the tuples of elements of the universe $D'$ of $\mathscr{M}'$ and where $\text{Rel}(\mathscr{M})$ is the set of the relations defined in model $\mathscr{M}$, whose universe is $D$. $f^\ast$ is defined as the function such that $f$ -my book says- *naturally extends to function* $f^\ast:\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M})\to\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M}')$, which I would say to mean that we can get an $n$-ary function $D^n\to\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M}'),$ $(d_1,\ldots,d_n)\mapsto f(d_1)\ldots f(d_n)$ (the concatenation of $f(d_1),\ldots ,f(d_n)$) and then get $f^\ast$ by "gluing" all the $n$-ary functions obtained in such a way.

Let a *countervariant interpretation* of model $\mathscr{M}$ in model $\mathscr{M}'$ be defined as a couple of functions $(f,g)$, with $f$ surjective, such that $$f:D'\twoheadrightarrow\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M})$$$$g:\text{Rel}(\mathscr{M})\to\text{Rel}(\mathscr{M}')$$$$\text{for any }\alpha\in\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M}') , R\in\text{Rel}(\mathscr{M})\quad\alpha\in g(R)\iff f^\ast(\alpha)\in R$$with the same notation as above. $f^\ast$ is defined as the function such that $f$ -my book says, again- *naturally extends to a function* $f^\ast:\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M}')\to\text{Seq}(\mathscr{M})$.

I read -in V. Manca's *Logica matematica*- that both a covariant interpretation and a countervariant interpretation of the model $\text{SEQ}=(\omega^\ast,--,||,0,\lambda)$ (where $--$ represents concatenation, $||$ the length of sequences and $\lambda$ is the empty sequence) of finite sequences of natural numbers in the model $\text{AR}=(\omega,+,\cdot,0,1)$ of standard arithmetic exist but I cannot see how to explicitly express them.

How can a covariant interpretation and a countervariant interpretations of $\text{SEQ}$ in $\text{AR}$ be built? I must add that the book gives no example of covariant or countervariant interpretations and I have found nothing on the Internet. I heartily thank you for any answer!

---

Some unfruitful trials: I do know that, if we call $x(i)$ the $i$-th element of sequence $x$, then $$\forall x\in \omega^\ast\quad\exists c,d\in\mathbb{N}:(\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,|x|\}\quad\beta(a,b,i)=x(i)\land\beta(a,b,0)=|x|)$$where $\beta(a,b,i)$ -Gödel's $\beta$ function- is the remainder of the division of $a$ by $(i+1)b+1$, but I have not been able to use that fact to build the interpretations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that is a very "formal" (and convoluted) way to express the "standard" [Gödel numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) technique (see also : [Gödel numbering for sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering_for_sequences)), i.e. :

> using Gödel numbering to encode unique sequences of symbols into unique natural numbers (i.e. place numbers into mutually exclusive or one-to-one correspondence with the sequences).

The key-features of the Gödel numbering encoding are : "effectivity", i.e. the encoding is computable or recursive, and "invertibility" :

- given a sequence we can effectively caculate its Gödel number
- given a Gödel number, we can effectively "unpack" it to recover the lenght of the encoded sequence and its $i$-th term.

---

You can see more "traditional" Gödel numberering descriptions in :

- Joseph Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.amazon.it/Mathematical-Logic-Joseph-R-Shoenfield/dp/1568811357/ref=sr_1_1?s=english-books&ie=UTF8&qid=1423857290&sr=1-1) (1967), **CH.6.4 Sequnce numbers**, page 115-on,

or :

- George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1 : Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&pg=PA155) (2003), **Ch.I.9. Arithmetic, Definability, Undefinability, and Incompletableness**, page 155-on.

---

See [Covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Covariance_and_contravariance) of *functors*.

---

---

In **Exercise 5.6** [page 158] we have the two models : $\mathscr{M} = \mathsf{SEQ}$ and $\mathscr{M}' = \mathsf{AR}$ with domains respectively $D=\omega^\ast$ : the set of finite sequences of *natural* numbers and $D'=\omega$.

We are searching for a couple of functions $f,g$ such that :

$$f:\omega^\ast \to \text{Seq}(\mathsf{AR})$$$$g:\text{Rel}(\mathsf{SEQ}) \to \text{Rel}(\mathsf{AR})$$ $$\text{for any }\alpha\in\text{Seq}(\mathsf{SEQ}) , R\in\text{Rel}(\mathsf{SEQ})\quad\alpha\in R\iff f^\ast(\alpha)\in g(R)$$

where $\text{Seq}(\mathsf{AR})$ is the set of the tuples of elements of the universe $D'=\omega$, i.e. tuples of *natural* numbers and where $\text{Rel}(\mathsf{SEQ})$ is the set of the relations defined in $\mathsf{SEQ}$, whose universe is $D=\omega^\ast$, i.e. finite sequences of *natural* numbers.

The hint points at Gödel's $\beta$-function [see **Exercise 4.6**, page 128]; the idea, as per your comment, is to use the encoding :

> > $(a_0,\ldots,a_n) \to (\Pi^n_{i=0}p^{ai+1}_i)$.

If we call this mapping $\mu$, we have that it maps $s \in \omega^\ast$ into $n \in \omega$, i.e. we have : $\mu : \omega^\ast \to \omega$. Thus, for any finite sequence $s$, $\mu(s)=n$ is its Gödel number.

In the Exerxises page 127-28 are described the "operations" with elements of $\mathsf{SEQ}$; we have to verify that e.g. the relation $x \in \alpha$, defined by :

> $\exists i(1 \le i \land i \le |\alpha| \land x=\alpha(i))$

can be "mapped" to a corresponding relation between numbers, and we have the $\beta$ function with the property that :

> for any $n$ and any $\alpha=(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ there are numbers $c,d$ such that : $\beta(c,d,i)=\alpha(i)$ for all $i \le n$.

Comment: Edited the OP with more details I had forgotten in the definitions of covariant and countervariant interpretation. Thank you for the hints!!!
Are you suggesting that the function $(a_0,...,a_n)\mapsto(\prod_{i=0}^n p_i^{a_i+1})$ where $p_0,...,p_n$ are the first $n+1$ prime number can be used as the covariant interpretation function $\omega^\ast\hookrightarrow\text{Seq}(\omega)$?

Comment: Nevertheless the function mapping $n=\prod_{i=0}^m p_i^{a_i+1}$ to $(a_0,...,a_m)$ cannot be used as the countervariant interpretation function $\omega\twoheadrightarrow\text{Seq}(\omega^\ast)$ because it is not defined for $n=1$: am I right? It will suffice for me to find any covariant and countervariant interpretations, even without using the $\beta$ function, but are $(a_0,...,a_n)\mapsto \prod_{i=0}^n p_i^{a_i+1}$ and $\beta$ related? I heartily thank you again!

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide - I've difficulty to follow the symbols of your book ... **In general**, not every number $n$ is the code number of a formula, **but** every formula has a **unique** code number. But be aware! the "general fact" must be proved for every specific encodig (there a many) and for every specific language (there are many). The coding is "effective", i.e. for any expression (it is a sequence of symbols) we can "mechanically" compute its encoding and for every number $n$ we can "mechabically" check if it is a code number and, if so, recover the corersponding expression.